# Why was my question on file comparison tools closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

I recently asked a question and it was closed and I cannot go back to view the answers in it.

Just curious as to why it was closed, it was on topic.

[question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160205/file-comparison-tool-that-will-allow-me-to-manually-remap-lines-between-two-file)

Comment: This may be related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142892/is-it-just-me-or-are-all-closed-questions-returning-an-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question appears to have been closed because it was asking for “shopping recommendations”. That's a somewhat derogatory term, but it refers to questions where you can't have a single most correct answer since there can be many products that are suitable (and the Stack Exchange system tries to avoid direct product comparisons of any kind). It's often possible to word a question so that it asks for a definitive answer and where a product recommendation would be a good answer, but somewhat challenging. However, it is definitely the case that “shopping recommendations” make poor Subjective Questions; they tend to attract argument, not enlightenment.

The reason you couldn't see it was just a site bug, now fixed.

Comment: Thanks!  It sort of shopping but I was asking for a specific feature so I thought it 'fit' the bill.  No worries though, I did get my answer and that's all that matters to me!